# error while executing the example spark streaming code JavaNetworkWordCount.java in eclipse

Tags: apache-spark

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: A master URL must be set in your configuration

> at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.(SparkContext.scala:185)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext$.createNewSparkContext(StreamingContext.scala:571)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.(StreamingContext.scala:74)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext.(JavaStreamingContext.scala:130)

Answer (score 1):

We need to set master with thread >1 while creating the sparkconf.

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf()
  .setAppName("JavaNetworkWordCount").setMaster("local[2]");
```